# router.use() works in local machine but when depolyed on server it does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, linux, npm

I have a angularJS application. It works fine on local machine but when configured on server it does not work. And I think that the issue is in `router.use('/', express.static(path.resolve('app')))`
Because when I comment the above line in local code it gives me the same error as I am getting in server. My server is the `ubuntu` machine.[image]

Comment: You should configure the server to reroute all requests to your index page, as is explained [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component-router#create-the-app-module).

Comment: I am using an older version of angularJS